# Is it possible to coerce 0x11 to 0x00, keeping 0x01 -> 0x01 and 0x -> 10 using only bitwise operations?

Tags: bit-manipulation

Is it possible to implement a function that results in this mapping:

```
{
  (0x01, 0x01),
  (0x10, 0x10),
  (0x11, 0x00)
}
```

Using only bitwise operations?

### Context

In the Flixel framework, there are a set of four constants,

```
FlxObject.LEFT:uint   = 0x0001;
FlxObject.RIGHT:uint  = 0x0010;
FlxObject.UP:uint     = 0x0100;
FlxObject.DOWN:uint   = 0x1000;
```

Obviously designed to be manipulated with bitwise operators. I was trying to write a function, using only bitwise operators, that would return the opposite direction of whatever was passed in (in terms of these FlxObject constants).

Some example mappings:

```
{
    (0x0110, 0x1001),
    (0x0100, 0x1000),
    (0x1010, 0x0101),
    (0x0001, 0x0010),
    (0x1100, 0x0000)
}
```

The problem is, my solution tends to break down when you pass it something like 0x0011, 0x1100, 0x1110 and similar, and requires a check against this case.
Testing code here (also at http://pastie.org/3420169):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import stdout
from os import linesep

# Implementation without conditional
def horiz(dir):
    return(dir ^ 0x0011 ^ 0x1100) & 0x0011

def vert(dir):
    return (dir ^ 0x1100 ^ 0x0011) & 0x1100
    
def oppositeDirection(dir):
    return horiz(dir) | vert(dir)


# Implementation with conditional
def horizFix(dir):
    dir = horiz(dir)
    return dir if dir != 0x0011 else 0

def vertFix(dir):
    dir = vert(dir)
    return dir if dir != 0x1100 else 0

def oppositeDirectionFix(dir):
    return horizFix(dir) | vertFix(dir)

failcount = 0
testcount = 0

def test(dir, expect, func):
    global failcount, testcount
    testcount += 1
    result = func(dir)
    stdout.write('Testing: {0:04x} => {1:04x}'.format(dir, result))
    if result != expect:
        stdout.write('\t GOT {0:04x} expected {1:04x}'.format(result, expect))
        failcount += 1
    stdout.write(linesep)

test_cases =[0x0000, 0x0001, 0x0010, 0x0100, 0x1000, 0x0011, 0x0101, 0x1001, 0x0110, 0x1010, 0x1100, 0x0111, 0x1011, 0x1101, 0x1110, 0x1111] 


print 'Testing full oppositeDirection function----------------'
for case in test_cases:
    test(case, oppositeDirectionFix(case), oppositeDirection)

print '\nTesting horiz function---------------------------------'
for case in test_cases:
    test(case, horizFix(case), horiz)

print '\nTesting vert function----------------------------------'
for case in test_cases:
    test(case, vertFix(case), vert)


print '{0}Succeeded: {2}/{1}, Failed: {3}/{1}'.format(linesep, testcount, testcount - failcount, failcount)
```

If you run the test, you'll see that in the cases like 0x0011 and 0x0000 horiz will return 0x0011, and for 0x1100 and 0x000 vert will return 0x1100. So close!

This is clearly an incredibly insignificant problem, and there will never be any situation in my game code where a direction value would be simultaneously left and right or up and down. But, I'm taking this as an opportunity to hone my bit twiddling skills. Is there some logic principle I'm missing here that will help me either solve it or realize it's an unsolvable problem?

Comment: Why did you say that "0x -> 10" in the title then make 01 -> 01 in the content? And what is the 4-bit mappings? They do not conform to the 2-bit mapping above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to make some kind of test because your result depends on two adjacent bits.

You could use `XOR` with `1111` and then test if the result contains `1100` or `0011`.

But since you only have 16 values to verify would it not be simpler to make a switch/select/match function for the 8 valid values?

Comment: You're right, the switch statement would be the most straightforward way to do this. I was just specifically looking for an opportunity to do some bit manipulation, not in the interest of productivity of anything.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question by now, but...
If bit shifts are allowed, then yes it can be done with just bitwise operations... though a lookup table or switch is probably more practical.  The trick is just that since the value of each bit in your result depends on more than one of your original bits, you need to incorporate a shifted copy of your input value into the overall operation.

If you change the definitions of `horiz()`, `vert()`, and `oppositeDirection()` in your testing code to the following:

```
def horiz(dir):
    return (((dir << 4) & ~dir & 0x0010) | ((dir >> 4) & ~dir & 0x0001))

def vert(dir):
    return (((dir << 4) & ~dir & 0x1000) | ((dir >> 4) & ~dir & 0x1000))

def oppositeDirection(dir):
    return (((dir << 4) & ~dir & 0x1010) | ((dir >> 4) & ~dir & 0x0101))
```

then all the tests pass.  If we look at `horiz()` (the others are similar):

The second digit (from the right) is given by:

```
((dir << 4) & ~dir & 0x0010)
```

and the first digit by:

```
((dir >> 4) & ~dir & 0x0001)
```

Looking further at how the first digit is calculated, `(dir >> 4)` gets us the original second digit, but lined up with the first.  `~dir` gets the inverse of the original digit.  We then AND those together, and AND with a mask to get just the digit we're calculating so we don't mess up the other digits.

So if we call the original digits A (first) and B (second), and call the new first digit X, we have:

```
X = ~A & B
```

The second digit is calculated the same way, shifting in the other direction.  We can also combine the calculations of the horizontal bits and the vertical ones by just adjusting the masks appropriately.